# onChange event on select box does nothing

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select input that should call a Javascript function when an option is chosen.

I'm using this code to do that:

```
<select id="main-category" name="main-category" class="dropdown" tabindex="2" onChange="showSubcats(this.value);">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value="1">First Option</option>
<option value="2">Second Option</option>
</select>
```

However, the `showSubcats()` function is never called when the selected option is changed. I tried testing it, I even tried calling a non-existent function to see if I'll get a Javascript error - nothing, the function is never called. What am I doing wrong?

It doesn't matter what the function is, let's say it's just `document.getElementById("some_id").innerHTML = "test"` which I have in there right now for testing purposes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NCjBp/. How about posting an example or the rest of your code? Where is the showSubcats function defined in your code?

Comment: This works for me (http://jsfiddle.net/Yh6ER/). You'll have to debug which of your code is *actually* causing the problem, and post that instead.

Comment: **If** your page is using an XHTML declaration and being served correctly (and so actually being processed as XHTML, not HTML tag soup), note that attribute names are case-sensitive. As Nicola Peluchetti pointed out in a now-deleted answer, in XHTML it would be `onchange` (in all lower case), not `onChange`.

Comment: It is the class='dropdown' part that is causing the problem. Removing it makes it work fine, which probably means there's some piece of Javascript, most likely jQuery, somewhere (I didn't create the site) that is related to it and stopping the onChange event. I guess I'll look into it myself, sorry for wasting everybody's time.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/8pnDw/

All I did was: change your function invocation to alert(...). It works perfectly.
If you're facing problems with your JavaScript, please let us know.

Hope it helps!